# Creating a view where 2 records from the same column get on the same row

Tags: mysql

(First of all I am new here so please notify me if I could do something better/different when asking a question)

I have a table in a MySQL database that looks like the following:

```
ID  Time    Object
1   10:00:05    1021
2   10:00:10    1021
3   10:00:15    1021
4   10:00:20    1021
5   10:00:25    1021
6   10:00:30    1021
7   10:00:35    1022
8   10:00:40    1022
9   10:00:45    1022
10  10:00:50    2300
11  10:00:55    2300
12  10:01:00    2300
14  10:01:10    2300 
15  10:01:15    2401
16  10:01:20    2503
18  10:01:30    2503
```

The reason that I want to do this in a view and not in a application is that I want to reduce the ammount of steps needed before the data is in the database.

Now what I would like to achieve to have as format in a view is the  following.
From all of the records in the original table I want to have the record after it on the same line. The record after doesnt always have a ID which is exactly 1 higher then the first one but it is always higher. The first record would be labeled with "_1" and the record after would be labeled with a "_2". I want to  do this for all 3 columns in the original table.

```
ID_1    ID_2    Time_1  Time_2  Object_1    Object_2
1        2     10:00:05 10:00:10    1021    1021
2        3     10:00:10 10:00:15    1021    1021
3        4     10:00:15 10:00:20    1021    1021
4        5     10:00:20 10:00:25    1021    1021
5        6     10:00:25 10:00:30    1021    1021
6        7     10:00:30 10:00:35    1021    1022
7        8     10:00:35 10:00:40    1022    1022
etc...
```

When I started creating a view I got stuck not managing to create the "2" columns.. I tried searching online for similar problems but couldnt find anything that worked for me.

This is the only thing I have sofar:

```
VIEW `View` AS
    SELECT 
        `Table`.`ID` AS `ID-1`,
        `Table`.`Time` AS `Time-1`,
        `Table`.`Object` AS `Object-1`

    FROM
        `Table`
    ORDER BY `Table`.`ID`
```

I hope someone might be able to help me/ push me into the right direction :)

Best regards,
L.Meijdam

Comment: How are you determining (differentiating) how to break down the columns?

Comment: Views serve almost no useful purpose in MySQL, so I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. Besides, this kind of thing is generally best handled in application code, if that's available.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. In particular use language to say, for a given row of values with the columns of your desired result, the conditions under which it belongs in the output. Ie explain what your example is an example *of*. It is not obvious. Not only is this for us to know what you need, and for your question to actually be a question rather than something vague, but for you to be able to find such solutions yourself, and in general reason & know what you are doing. PS Clarify via post edits, not comments.

Comment: @Strawberry Mm. I have made use of them but only for development/debugging - automatic decoding of certain complex fields so that I can scan through table contents faster. Can't think of much else to do with them frankly

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are joining odd number id to next id so a self join might do with a mod (%) test

```
select t.id,t1.id,t.time,t1.time,t.object,t1.object
from t
left join t t1 on t1.id = t.id + 1 and t.object = t1.object
where t.id % 2 > 0
order by t.object,t.id;

+------+------+----------+----------+--------+--------+
| id   | id   | time     | time     | object | object |
+------+------+----------+----------+--------+--------+
|    1 |    2 | 10:00:05 | 10:00:10 |   1021 |   1021 |
|    3 |    4 | 10:00:15 | 10:00:20 |   1021 |   1021 |
|    5 |    6 | 10:00:25 | 10:00:30 |   1021 |   1021 |
|    7 |    8 | 10:00:35 | 10:00:40 |   1022 |   1022 |
|    9 | NULL | 10:00:45 | NULL     |   1022 |   NULL |
|   11 |   12 | 10:00:55 | 10:01:00 |   2300 |   2300 |
|   13 |   14 | 10:01:05 | 10:01:10 |   2300 |   2300 |
|   15 | NULL | 10:01:15 | NULL     |   2401 |   NULL |
|   17 |   18 | 10:01:25 | 10:01:30 |   2503 |   2503 |
+------+------+----------+----------+--------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

if you don't trust that the id is continuous (and you probably shouldn't) then if you have mysql version 8 or better use lag function, if lower than 8 user row number simulation.

With row number simulation the code looks like this

```
select tid,t1id,ttime,t1time,tobject,t1object
from
(
select t.id tid,t.time ttime, t.object tobject, 
        if(t.object<> @p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
        @p:=t.object p
from t
cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by object , time
) t
left join
(
select t.id t1id, t.time t1time, t.object t1object,
        if(t.object<> @p1,@rn1:=1,@rn1:=@rn1+1) rn,
        @p1:=t.object p
from t
cross join (select @rn1:=0,@p1:=0) r
order by object , time
) t1
on t1object = tobject and t1.rn = t.rn + 1
where t.rn % 2 > 0
order by tobject,tid;
```

A bit more verbose but possibly more robust also.

Comment: I tried this query but the ID's do not match the output I hope to achieve, please note that I edited the question in the hope my question is more clear now. You were right about the fact that I shouldnt trust the ID's to be continuous since they were not.

Comment: just remove the where condition

Comment: That worked! The only problem I have now is that at some records the t1 records give Null on all t1 columns. This seems to happen when the tobject is not the same as t1object. I however do need these records.

Answer (score 0):

you need to join the table to itself and give each of them with a separate name
then choose whichever column you want from each table.

    `` SELECT 
        t1.`ID` AS `ID-1`,
        t2.`ID` AS `ID-2`,
        .
        .
        .
    FROM
        `posrep` as t1 join `posrep` as t2
    WHERE <how you plan to decide on each value> ``

Answer (score 0):

Try this please replace `test` by your table name:

```
            SELECT  a.id as ID_1,
                b.id as ID_2,
                a.Time as Time_1,
                b.Time as Time_2,
                a.Object as Object_1,
                b.Object as Object_2
            FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM `test`) as a,
            (SELECT * FROM `test`) as b 
            WHERE a.id+1 = b.id
```

Comment: This worked for my example data set, but I found out that in the real dataset the ID is'nt always exactly 1 higher(sometimes more then 1). I updated my example dataset so that the difference in ID isnt always 1.

Answer (score -1):

Create your view with following sql query and replace 'table_name' with your actual table name.

Select ID as ID_1 ,ID+1 as ID_2 from 'table_name' ;

Comment: Hi this will not work since, The record after doesnt always have a ID which is exactly 1 higher then the first one but it is always higher.

Comment: I am not very sure but what you can do is retrieve the same table in a view and delete first row from it. And retrieve the ID column from both the views so that it will get shifted up